Construcción de un SummarizedExperimet con un experimento de GEO
Con un experimento de GEO con código PRJNA1021663, tengo que construir un SummarizeExperiment a partir de su matriz de conteos y añadiendo las variables fenotípicas. El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:
library(readr)
raw_counts <- read_delim("C:/GSE244210_raw_counts_GRCh38.p13_NCBI.tsv/      GSE244210_raw_counts_GRCh38.p13_NCBI.tsv", 
delim = "\t", escape_double = FALSE, 
trim_ws = TRUE)

# Asignar la primera columna como nombres de filas
rownames(raw_counts) <- raw_counts$GeneID

# Eliminar la primera columna
#raw_counts <- raw_counts[, -1]

# Convertimos en matriz
raw_counts <- as.matrix(raw_counts) 
class(raw_counts)

# Creamos data.frame para información fenotípica
sample_names <- colnames(raw_counts)
phenotypes <- data.frame(
sample_name = sample_names,
phenotype = c(
    rep("hhv6_in_bal", 2),
    rep("hhv6_in_blood", 2)),
replicate = rep(1:2, 2),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
rownames(phenotypes) <- sample_names

# Creamos Summarized Experiment
library(SummarizedExperiment)
se <- SummarizedExperiment(
assays = list(counts = raw_counts),
colData = phenotypes
)

Mi pregunta es si esto sería correcto y siendo mi experimento el que se ve en la siguiente imagen, si me faltaría alguna variable fenotípica o cuales serían mis variables fenotípicas?
